# Does `tf.repeat` exist in TensorFlow for Swift

Tags: swift, tensorflow, swift-for-tensorflow

Is there an equivalent of **tf.repeat** in TensorFlow Swift. I cant seem to find it anywhere on the main apis or in .Raw functions.

Thanks

Comment: I am using version 0.11 of TensorFlow Swift (with Xcode 12 beta).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, [`tiled(multiples:)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/swift/api_docs/Structs/Tensor#/s:10TensorFlow0A0V5tiled9multiplesACyxGACys5Int32VG_tF) on Tensor should replicate [tf.repeat](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/repeat)'s functionality. For example,

```
import TensorFlow
let tensor = Tensor<Float>([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
let repeatTensor = tensor.tiled(multiples: [2])
```

will produce a `repeatTensor` of `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]`.

Comment: I don't think tiled gives quite the same power. with tiled each value is repeated the same number of times: 

    tf.repeat([1.0,2.0], [1,2]) = [1.0,2.0,2.0]

Answer (score 0):

best way I have found so far uses _Raw.raggedRange.

```
func rowIdsFrom(lengths: Tensor<Int32>) -> Tensor<Int32> {
        let starts = Tensor<Int32>(rangeFrom: Int32(0), to: lengths.shape[0], stride: 1)
        let (_, indices1) : (Tensor<Int32>, Tensor<Int32>) = _Raw.raggedRange(starts: starts, limits: starts + lengths, deltas: Tensor.one)
        let (_, indices2) : (Tensor<Int32>, Tensor<Int32>) = _Raw.raggedRange(starts: Tensor.zero, limits: lengths, deltas: Tensor.one)
        return indices1 - indices2
}
func repeat(values: Tensor<Scalar>, lengths: Tensor<Int32>) -> Tensor<Scalar> {
        return values.gathering(atIndices: rowIdsFrom(lengths: lengths))
}
```